# Is it impossible to fold a sheet of paper in half more than seven times?

Tags: physics

It's a commonly stated belief that no one can fold a piece of paper in half after doing so seven times. Even I have been unable to fold a piece of normal paper for an 8th time.

**Is this true for normal (A4/newspaper) sized-paper?**

I would also be interested to know if this is this an absolute rule, or would a sufficiently large piece of paper be foldable more than seven times?

Comment: Define `normal`. Isn't newspaper paper normal? Airpost?

Comment: mythbusters covered this one. However, the clip I found [uses a massive sheet](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRAEBbotuIE)

Comment: I got to 9 (using extra thin A4 paper) so this is officially BUSTED.

Comment: You also need to define if all the folds have to be in the same direction.  I have taken an 8.5" x 11" piece of paper, folded it 5-6 times in one direction (along the longer axis, i.e. left-to-right), then was able to fold it 3-4 more times along the shorter (although now longer) axis, i.e. up-to-down.

Comment: People interested in origami find this statement outright hilarious :)

Comment: There are no absolutes.

Comment: This video shows that an A3 sheet of paper cannot be folded more then 7 times https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KuG_CeEZV6w

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**No**, it is not true for all scenarios.

This idea was examined by Britney Gallivan, who came up with a mathematical model for the limits, and used this knowledge to fold a large piece of paper twelve times in January 2002.

She was a junior in high school at the time.

Reference: [Historical Society of Pomona Valley](http://pomonahistorical.org/12times.htm)

---

According to the above reference, the upper-bound equation for "Alternate Direction Folding", which I understand to be the normal style, is

[image: Formula]

Without LaTeX, this looks like:

> W = πt.2^(3(n-1)/2)

Solve for n, we get:

> n = 1 + 2/3.log<sub>2</sub> (W/πt)

Plugging in the values for standard A4 80 g/m² office copy paper (W=[297mm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size), t=[0.105mm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_density)) we get:

> n = 1 + 2/3.log<sub>2</sub>(297/(0.105π))
>
> n = 7.543

Notes:

- The equation works with square paper, and I have used A4's longest side, perhaps overestimating the number of folds by a fraction.
- The thickness of 80 g/m² was interpolated from the chart on cited page.
- Pi looks like this, in this font: π

If the original formula calculated by Gallivan is correct, this shows that a standard piece of copy paper, even if it is extended a little, cannot be folded 8 times.

Comment: I particularly like this answer because a secondary school student figured it out and provided an answer that included a mathematical model.  (_I hope this helps encourage more younger people to engage in scientific thinking._)

Comment: for A4 it may well be true, iirc to get more folds you need a very long thin piece of paper such as toilet paper

Comment: @jk - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRAEBbotuIE here is supersized to 11 from mythbusters.

Comment: It's important to note that Ms. Gallivan foled a very large sheet of paper. Since the OP asked for a A4 sized paper, your answer could be improved by saying how many times that sheet of paper can be folded by using the model you cite.

Comment: @Borror0 edited the question to imply that we are talking about any ordinary paper that we make use of in our day-to-day basis.

Comment: @Borror0: Ah, the question has been changed since I answered it. My answer addresses the original question.

Comment: @Oddthinking: It would be ideal to update your answer around the lines of "It is/isn't possible, as the laws governing folding of paper are X. However, it is possible if Y."

Comment: @Borror0: You aren't making it easy. I'll have a stab.

Comment: Questions also mentions "newspaper size". Newspapers are printed on much thinner paper ( between 40 g/m2 and 57 g/m2), full sized newspaper sheet is 24"x36" (already folded once, containing 4 pages of newspaper). Result for above formula for 40g/m2 24x36" sheet is **9.26**